# Using MassTransit with Microsoft Storage Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-emulator

I've been trying to get a working configuration up and running using MassTransit with Microsoft Storage Emulator. But no matter what I try and cannot get it work.

The only details I get on this setup is here http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/transports/azure.html

**Setup**

- My emulator is running
- I have a queue setup
- I have created a access policy
- Created a SAS

When I create a SAS I get a url that looks like this http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1/validation?sv=2015-12-11&si=validation-1574305821E&sig=dM8amgmEXM8ykQwLpnrBI2AJmBS3agOvtR%2FskAJJqec%3D

But I cant use it as Masstransit complains the protocol needs to be "sb://" not "http://"

The code I have at the moment is

```
void Main()
{
    var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
            {

                var host = sbc.Host("sb://127.0.0.1", h =>                
                {
                    h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("devstoreaccount1", "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==");

                });

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("validation", a => 
                    {

                    }
                );
            });

        var o = new Person(){Name = "Bob", DOB = new DateTime(1978, 10, 20) };

        busControl.Start();
        busControl.Publish(o);
        busControl.Stop();

}

public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime DOB {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried the token with

- Account name: devstoreaccount1
- Account key:   Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==

referred in this https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/includes/storage-emulator-connection-string-include.md

The line of code it errors on is the busControl.Start();

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: In trying to read through your question, it sounded like you expected Azure Service Bus to be running locally under the Storage Emulator - the Storage Emulator doesn't emulate Service Bus.

Comment: Thank you brenden. That explains why I cant use it.